# How to properly register javascript form an ASP.NET Master Page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have been using the code below for several years in my ASP.NET VB website.  All of the sudden I am getting the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

*Code From Master Pager Code Behind:*

```
MyJavaScript = "<script language='javascript'>function(){getElementByName('MyLabel').style.display = 'none';</script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onload", MyJavaScript)
```

*Rendered In Browser As:*

```
<script language='javascript'>function(){getElementByName('MyLabel').style.display = 'none';</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyJavaScript = "<script language='javascript'>function(){getElementByName('MyLabel').style.display = 'none';}</script>"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onload", MyJavaScript)
```